# How to write a group statement that shows if Payer = 'Residential Options' or 'Residential Options ICF',Facility, else '' )

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

This is my code **=IIF(Fields!Payer.Value = "Residential Options" OR "Residential Options ICF", RTRIM(Fields!Facility.Value) ,"", " ") **

Facility (Will need to do a formula: if Payer = 'Residential Options' or 'Residential Options ICF',
Facility, else '' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the Field in the OR - there's nothing like the IN in SQL server that lets the user have multiple choices.

```
=IIF(
    Fields!Payer.Value = "Residential Options" OR Fields!Payer.Value = "Residential Options ICF"
    ,RTRIM(Fields!Facility.Value) 
    ,""
    )
```